# RestKit. Prevent from directly storing to CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I've integrated `RestKit` for my iOS project in Objective C, every thing is great. I've created mappings for my `NSManagedObject` model classes, and want to store resulted objects to `CoreData` db. But one thing that `RestKit` is directly storing received datas to db and after that it's firing `success` block where I'm reloading `tableView`. My problem is that I don't want `RestKit` store the received datas directly to db, but want to check(or modify) the mapped response and then save.

I found this post
[RestKit CoreData 0.20.3 - additional check before saving the MOC after mapping finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716502/restkit-coredata-0-20-3-additional-check-before-saving-the-moc-after-mapping-f).
But there I couldn't find answer for my problem.

Can Someone give me solutions?

Comment: Why not? It's the correct solution to your question

Comment: I saw that with the `Key-Value Validation` I can make some transformations at mapping time, Anyway after mapping `RestKit` stores results to db automatically. And `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert` property discards object when they fail `validateForInsert`. But I want that RestKit gave me mapped results only on `success` block, and storing them I will make myself.

Comment: Can't do that with core data objects. You'd need to use plain objects and then convert them yourself.